# Error Handling with Live Data Matlab

Tags: api, matlab, live

I am using a live data API that is returning the next arriving trains. I plan on giving the user the next 5 trains arriving. If there are less than 5 trains arriving, how you handle that? I am having trouble thinking of a way, I was thinking a way with if statements but don't know how I would set them up.

```
time1Depart = dataReturnedFromLiveAPI{1,1}.orig_departure_time;
time2Depart = dataReturnedFromLiveAPI{1,2}.orig_departure_time;
time3Depart = dataReturnedFromLiveAPI{1,3}.orig_departure_time;
time4Depart = dataReturnedFromLiveAPI{1,4}.orig_departure_time;
time5Depart = dataReturnedFromLiveAPI{1,5}.orig_departure_time;

time1Arrival = dataReturnedFromLiveAPI{1,1}.orig_arrival_time;
time2Arrival = dataReturnedFromLiveAPI{1,2}.orig_arrival_time;
time3Arrival = dataReturnedFromLiveAPI{1,3}.orig_arrival_time;
time4Arrival = dataReturnedFromLiveAPI{1,4}.orig_arrival_time;
time5Arrival = dataReturnedFromLiveAPI{1,5}.orig_arrival_time;
```

The code right now uses a matrix that goes from 1:numoftrains but I am using just the first five.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bad practice to assign individual value to a separate variable. Better if you pass all related values to a vector or cell array depending on class of `orig_departure_time` and `orig_arrival_time`.

It looks like `dataReturnedFromLiveAPI` is a cell array of structures. Then you can do:

```
timeDepart = cellfun(@(x), x.orig_departure_time, ...
    dataReturnedFromLiveAPI(1,1:min(5,size(dataReturnedFromLiveAPI,2))), ...
    'UniformOutput',0 );
timeArrival = cellfun(@(x), x.orig_arrival_time, ...
    dataReturnedFromLiveAPI(1,1:min(5,size(dataReturnedFromLiveAPI,2))), ...
    'UniformOutput',0 );
```

Then you how to access the values one by one as

```
time1Depart = timeDepart{1};
```

If `orig_departure_time` and `orig_arrival_time` are numeric scalars, you can use `...'UniformOutput',1...`. You will get output as a vector and can get single values with `timeDepart(1)`.